# Adding Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

In Eclipse we were able to add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml by going to AndroidManifest.xml->Permission-> Adding permissions.

How to add permissions in Android Studio? How can we get a list of all the permissions that we can add to an Activity ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Help! None of the answers seem to work in current version 2.2.1.  The manifest visible in the tree and editor is an empty placeholder with nothing but a comment. How do i edit the real thing?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can only type them manually, but the content assist helps you there, so it is pretty easy.

Add this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission."/>
```

and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> after the dot (or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> on Mac). If you need an explanation for the permission, you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: Where is the manifest file in the project tree in Android Studio?

Comment: Oh, just found it using the Android View in the project tree.

Comment: @djondal I used to find any file in Android studio by ctrl + shift + n this could be a better way to reach instead of straining your eyes.

Comment: this must be one of those ways android studio is better than eclipse.

Comment: Is there any particular context regarding *where* in the manifest file we add this, or can we just add it wherever?

Comment: @djondal Expand **Projects Tab->Select Android->App->manifests**

Comment: In Mac is ctrl + space as well. cmd + space actually launchs Spotlight from any application.
However, to display "explanation" or, rather  "Quick documentation look up", in Mac, press Ctrl + j instead of Ctrl + q.
Check here if you want to see all keyboard shortcuts: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 64):

You can type them manually but the editor will assist you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

You can see the snap sot below.

[image]

As soon as you type "a" inside the quotes you get a list of permissions and also hint to move caret up and down to select the same.

[image]

Answer (score 58):

Go to Android Manifest.xml
and be sure to add the `<uses-permission tag >` **inside** the manifest tag but **Outside** of all other tags..

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

This is an example of the permission of using Internet.

Answer (score 8):

You can add manually in the manifest file within manifest tag by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

This permission is required to be able to access the camera device.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple.

All you need to do is:

- Right click above application tag and click on Generate
- Click on XML tag
- Click on user-permission
- Enter the name of your permission.

Answer (score 3):

**Put these two line in your AndroidMainfest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```