# How to get GUI to edit androidmanifest.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android technology. I installed Android Studio and want to add Application attributes in the **androidmanifest.xml** for the sake of Shared Preferences.

Unlike eclipse, Android studio is giving only XML editor, not the GUI to edit manifest file. How to get GUI in Android Studio, else should I write the xml manually? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't the site you are looking for. EDIT: 1 second on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948537/adding-permissions-in-androidmanifest-xml-in-android-studio

Comment: How to add shared reference class names in manifest file?