# Android googlemap permission check, cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android

I got sample code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location?hl=en

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
} else {
    // Show rationale and request permission.
}
```

I uses above codes, but in Android Studio, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is described as `cannot resolve symbol ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` with red color font. I already put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` on my Androidmanifest

What should i do to solve this?

Comment: check this answer i think its helpful [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948537/adding-permissions-in-androidmanifest-xml-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do import manifest manually.

Put `import android.Manifest;`import part of activity.java